# Customize a checkout field if there are applied coupons in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

In need to control the order notes checkout field if a coupon is applied in Woocommerce: I have tried this will no success.

```
add_action('woocommerce_applied_coupon', 'apply_product_on_coupon');
function apply_product_on_coupon( ) {
    if (WC()->cart->has_discount('test')) {
        $fields['billing']['billing_customer_note']['placeholder'] = 'You can have up to three initials';
        $fields['billing']['billing_customer_note']['label'] = 'Personalise your Tote bag';
        $fields['billing']['billing_customer_note']['required'] = true;
        $fields['billing']['billing_customer_note']['input_class'] = array('tote-bag');
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

I know the $fields bit works as I have used this in a different scenario. If we assume that the coupon code is 'test' I need the order notes to be mandatory, the label and placeholder changed and some additional CSS classes applied.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The code from Team dolphin don't use the right way, as each time customer will add or remove a coupon in checkout, the page will be reloaded (and customer will loose all fields inputed data). Also the field is not validated as mandatory if customer try to place order without filling order notes when there is an applied coupon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with this code. Add this code in your active theme functions.php file.

summer is coupon code name. replace with your coupon code name

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'xa_remove_billing_checkout_field');
function xa_remove_billing_checkout_field($fields) {
    global $woocommerce;
    if (!empty(WC()->cart->applied_coupons)){
        if (in_array("summer", WC()->cart->applied_coupons)) {
            $fields['order']['order_comments']['required'] = true;
            $fields['order']['order_comments']['placeholder'] ='custom placeholder';
            $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = 'custom label';   
            $fields['order']['order_comments']['input_class'] = array('tote-bag');
        }
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Hope is useful for you. Thanks

**UPDATE**

If you remove coupon from checkout then refresh the page.

```
function action_woocommerce_removed_coupon( $coupon_code ) { 
    if ($coupon_code == "summer") { ?>
        <script>location.reload();</script>
    <?php }
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_removed_coupon', 'action_woocommerce_removed_coupon', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Almost. I had to use my code to display the order notes but the conditional works as I need it to. That said if I remove the coupon, the changes are not removed. Any ideas?

Comment: It's work if you remove coupon remove from cart

Answer (score 1):

As customer can add or remove a coupon in Checkout page, jQuery and Php are required.

Only if a coupon code is applied to the order, the following code will make checkout order notes field required, changing its label and placeholder, and adding tote-bag as selector class to textarea input field. It will handle validation when the field is required.

Use the following code instead:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'custom_order_notes_checkout_fields_js');
function custom_order_notes_checkout_fields_js($fields) {
    // Here below set your custom order notes attributes (when a coupon is applied)
    $field_label = __('custom label');
    $placeholder = __('custom placeholder');
    $label       = 'tote-bag';

    $required    = '<abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr>';

    wc_enqueue_js( "jQuery(function($){
        var required     = '".$required."',
            label        = '".$field_label."',
            placeholder  = '".$placeholder."',
            input_class  = '".$input_class."',
            class_requ   = 'validate-required',
            class_valid  = 'woocommerce-validated',
            class_unval  = 'woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field',
            notesPara    = '#order_comments_field',
            notesLabel   = notesPara+' label',
            notesText    = notesPara+' textarea',
            defaultLabel = $(notesText).html(),
            defaultPHold = $(notesText).attr('placeholder'),
            newLabel     = label+'&nbsp'+required;

            console.log(defaultPHold);

        if( $('tr.cart-discount').length > 0 ) {
            $(notesPara).addClass(class_requ).addClass(class_valid);
            $(notesLabel).html(newLabel);
            $(notesText).attr('placeholder', placeholder);
        }

        // On order notes change
        $(document.body).on('change input', notesText, function(){
            if( $('tr.cart-discount').length > 0 ) {
                if( $(this).val() != '' ) {
                    $(notesPara).removeClass(class_unval);
                    if ( ! $(notesPara).hasClass(class_valid) ) {
                        $(notesPara).addClass(class_valid);
                    }
                } else {
                    $(notesPara).removeClass(class_valid);
                    if ( ! $(notesPara).hasClass(class_unval) ) {
                        $(notesPara).addClass(class_unval);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // On coupon change
        $(document.body).on('updated_checkout', function(){
            if( $('tr.cart-discount').length > 0 ) {
                if( ! $(notesPara).hasClass(class_requ) ) {
                    $(notesPara).addClass(class_requ).addClass(class_valid);
                    $(notesLabel).html(newLabel);
                    $(notesText).addClass(input_class);
                    $(notesText).attr('placeholder', placeholder);
                }
            } else {
                if( $(notesPara).hasClass(class_requ) ) {
                    $(notesPara).removeClass(class_requ).removeClass(class_valid).removeClass(class_unval);
                    $(notesLabel).html(defaultLabel);
                    $(notesText).addClass(input_class);
                    $(notesText).attr('placeholder', defaultPHold);
                }
            }
        });
    });");
}

// Enable "Order notes" field validation for applied coupons
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'validation_checkout_required_order_comments');
function validation_checkout_required_order_comments() {
    $applied_coupons = WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons();
    if ( ! empty($applied_coupons) && isset($_POST['order_comments']) && strlen($_POST['order_comments']) < 3 ) {
        wc_add_notice( __("Order comments is a required custom field whan a coupon is applied", "woocommerce"), 'error' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec - where does your code check for the coupon name?