# Woocommerce - Calcutlate Shipping cost on total amount of order, but without coupon

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

first of all I am not a pro developer and for a customer we have the following request.
Currently, in Woocommerce the shipping cost is calcutlated on basis of the total order amount ([fee percent="8"]) --> 8% of the order amount.

The customer wants now that if a coupon is applied the shipping cost should be calculated on the basis of the original amount NOT the new total amount with the coupon amount.

Any idea to resolve that smoothly ?

Thanks !
Julian

Answer (score 0):

You need to use woocommerce_package_rates filter hook in which get total cart amount except coupon amount and changes shiiping cost for each shipping rates in loop. Let me know if you getting any issue.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_costs', 10, 2 );
function custom_shipping_costs( $rates, $package ) {
    $carttotal = WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
    
    $taxes = array();
    foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
        if( $rates[$rate_key]->taxes[$key] > 0 ){
            $taxes[$key] = $carttotal * 0.08;
        }
    }
    $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
}
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: @Tyler2P I updated my answer let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: Hey thanks for providing this ! Unfortunately, this doesn't work and after adding this to functions.php of child theme no shipping is displayed and all shipping methods are gone ...

Answer (score 0):

Here are my solutions:

1.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_costs', 20, 2 );
function custom_shipping_costs( $rates, $package ) {
global $woocommerce;
    
    if (!empty(WC()->cart->applied_coupons)){
    
    $totalfees = WC()->cart->get_fees();  //$order->get_total_fees();
    $producttotal = WC()->cart->subtotal; // $order->get_subtotal();
    $total = (float)$totalfees + (float)$producttotal;
    
   // New shipping cost (can be calculated)
    $new_cost = $total * .08;
    $tax_rate = array();

    foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        // Excluding free shipping methods
        if( $rate->method_id != 'free_shipping'){

            // Set rate cost
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $new_cost;

            // Set taxes rate cost (if enabled)
            $taxes = array();
            foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $rates[$rate_key]->taxes[$key] > 0 )
                    $taxes[$key] = $new_cost * $tax_rate;
            }
            $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;

        }
    }
    
    return $rates;
}
}
```

2. 

```
if(!empty( $order->get_used_coupons() )) {

    $totalfees = $order->get_total_fees();
    $producttotal = $order->get_subtotal();
    $total = (float)$totalfees + (float)$producttotal;
    

// Get the customer country code
$country_code = $order->get_shipping_country();

// Set the array for tax calculations
$calculate_tax_for = array(
    'country' => $country_code,
    'state' => '', // Can be set (optional)
    'postcode' => '', // Can be set (optional)
    'city' => '', // Can be set (optional)
);

// Optionally, set a total shipping amount
$new_ship_price =  $total * .08;

// Get a new instance of the WC_Order_Item_Shipping Object
$item = new WC_Order_Item_Shipping();

$item->set_method_title( "Flat rate" );
$item->set_method_id( "flat_rate:14" ); // set an existing Shipping method rate ID
$item->set_total( $new_ship_price ); // (optional)
$item->calculate_taxes($calculate_tax_for);

$order->add_item( $item );

$order->calculate_totals();

$order->update_status('on-hold');

// $order->save(); // If you don't update the order status
}
```

Resources [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169568/check-if-any-coupon-code-is-applied-in-woocommerce) , [2](https://coderedirect.com/questions/165301/add-a-shipping-to-an-order-programmatically-in-woocommerce-3), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66706666/customize-a-checkout-field-if-there-are-applied-coupons-in-woocommerce), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786788/set-custom-shipping-rates-programmatically-in-woocommerce-3)